# TypeError: metaclass conflict in python

Tags: python, django, inheritance, tastypie, metaclass

I am using django-tastypie to create a rest API for my webapp. 
I want to create classes like mentioned below without typing them all out explicitly(I have more than a 100 classes)

```
class CityResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = City.objects.all()
class StateResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = State.objects.all()
etc...
```

I was thinking of using metaclasses in python(my approach might be wrong but still want to solve it this way as I want to see how metaclass can help me and maybe a good way to learn it in a real life problem)

I tried this:

```
class ClassFactory(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

for model in get_models(app):
    name = "%sResource" % model._meta.object_name
    ClassFactory(name, (ModelResource, ), {'Meta':type('Meta', (), {'queryset': model.objects.all()})})
```

But this gives an error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I googled up on this and everywhere it mentions about how if a class derives from 2 other classes that have two different metaclass then the class I make must have a metaclass that was derived from the two metaclasses[*].

1. How does this error happen in my case, as I am deriving from the same class ModelResource?
2. I am not sure I understand [*]

I might be solving this problem the wrong way, but need some pointers.

Comment: "(my approach might be wrong but still want to solve it this way)" I never understand this attitude. If your approach is wrong, change it. I don't have anything constructive to say here, since django often makes you do things that you wouldn't normally have to do, but don't knowingly dismiss a potential better way to do what you're doing.

And yes, 100 classes sounds like madness.

Comment: My idea is to learn how metaclasses would help me here which is why I am asking this question. To primarily learn how to write metaclasses for this and if possible also learn why this approach might be wrong if at all. This is the attitude. I always thought it's fine to ask such questions atleast on SO.

Comment: Also, the question has really got nothing to do with django

Comment: I think you should learn how to use metaclasses when you have a problem that should be solved with a metaclass (which is exceedingly rare, and prominent Python core devs have said approaches being needed by less than 1% of Python developers). I'm not saying it's not necessary here, it may be, but it's something to keep in mind. As for what questions are appropriate for SO, I have no idea, but I should hope ones that help you write good code would be the benchmark.

Comment: Well, I agree to what you say and which is what I have done and I have stumbled upon this idea of using metaclasses for this matter. It's like my own little discovery and I would like to know how to solve it. I would regard SO not only for writing good code but mainly as a knowledge discovery tool which 99% of the times it is when you find an answer to your problem from stackoverflow and you find a never to be seen method of solving it, I feel. Anyhow, we must not digress so much. I think we both get each others point of views

Comment: I don't think you need the `ClassFactory` "metaclass" at all. `type(name, (ModelResource, ), {...})` should return a new class that's derived from ModelResource, as you want.

Comment: @AKX thanks, that worked. You can post this as the answer. What did I do wrong with making a ClassFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Reposted from comment.)

I don't think you need the `ClassFactory` "metaclass" at all.

```
klass = type(name, (ModelResource, ), {...})
```

should get you a new class that's derived from ModelResource, as you want.